# Conclusion for not rejecting a null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, sampling, odds-ratio

I'm actually quite confused what is the outcome we could deduce here for the other exercise types listed in the diagram.

From my interpretation, the null-hypothesis is: There is no association between the said exercise type and ADL disability among community-dwelling woman in Itabashi Ward.

And the alternative hypothesis: There is a negative association between the said exercise type and ADL disability among community-dwelling woman in Itabashi Ward. [1 Tail test]

So from the Confidence Intervals(CI), we can see that the null hypothesis is only rejected for dancing, but not the rest of the exercises. We would usually say there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis, but actually we mean that it is impossible to be the alternative hypothesis. So is it even correct to say that there is no association for the other exercises and ADL disability?

Here's an online [copy](http://itarget.com.br/newclients/sbgg.com.br/informativos/28-12-18/5%20Exercise%20type%20and%20activities%20of%20daily%20living%20disability.pdf) of the research article.

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: "actually we mean that it is impossible to be the alternative hypothesis" -- this is not a valid conclusion if you fail to reject a null.

Comment: So what exactly is the conclusion when u fail to reject null? For the case of the other exercises, can u even say there's an association?

Comment: You can't make any conclusion when you fail to reject the null hypothesis. There may be a negative association in the population that you failed to detect, or there may be no association in the population (there may even be a positive association). The data do not provide any way to distinguish among these options. There is no conclusion to be made.